# What is the main use of interpreter files?

Tags: c, unix, exec

I read the concepts interpretor files. but i don't know what is the use of that.
consider i had a exec function as

```
  execl("/home/bhuvanesh/hello.sh","hello.sh","-l",NULL);
```

in that hello.sh i have the interpreter as

```
  #!/bin/ls
```

when i am executing the exec program it will work like a

```
   "ls -l hello.sh"
```

option in linux.. what is the main reason to use this interpreter files??
i thought that "/home/bhuvanesh/hello.sh" this will replaced by /bin/ls. but this "/home/bhuvanesh/hello.sh" will taken as a first argument for the ls command .

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg - I can't understand .. please explain deeply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpreter file is the program that runs the rest of the script.
The main use of specifying an interpreter file is to make it easier to run the program and to make sure the correct interpreter is used.

If you want to run the perl scipt myPerlProgram you type:

```
$ perl myPerlProgram
```

If you have a perl program with an interpreter file you only need to type:

```
$ myPerlProgram
```

and the program will run with perl as interpreter.

This is relly nifty for shell scripts. There are several different shells (for example sh, csh, bash, zsh) and by specifying the interpreter you can make sure your program is run by the correct shell.